# create custom keyboard shortcut windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editors, ubuntu-16.04

I am looking for a way to create my own custom keyboard shortcuts in windows 10 or ubuntu 16.04, for all programs (not just MS word or my text editors).
what i want to do is be able to copy, paste and hold in memory more than one object.
for example if i select some text and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> it would hold the selected text and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> would paste it.
i want the same key combination to work in all text editing in my OS with the ability to set at least 2 selected texts.

if anyone has a solution for at least one of the operating systems i would like to hear it.

Comment: To my knowledge, users can only create Custom Keyboard Shortcuts for apps.
https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-windows10/
cannot create the key combination to achieve operation function such as select and paste.

Answer (score 0):

So i also asked this in ask ubuntu and the solution is apperently available in the form of a clipboard manager, of which there are multiple choices.
some of which allow me to select which keyboard shortcuts to use.